# iOS: Localization LaunchImage Trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization

I have an app with deployment target sets up to 7.1 (so I can't use .xib launchImage). I want to use different images for each language in my project. After researching I found that it could be removed from .xcassets catalog and should be called Default.png (added to .plist too). I have 3 files for (iPhone 4s, 5/5s, 6)

> Default@2x.png
>
> Default-568h@2x.png
>
> Default-667h@2x.png

If I simple add these files to project it works correctly but when I touch in right-sided File Inspector Localize button and added some languages my app is starting without launchImage and my interface flattened from top and bottom.

Comment: What do you mean by "interface flattened from top and bottom"?

Comment: @YuchenZhong thanks for reply. I mean black bars at top and bottom of my screen

Comment: You can localize info.plist and set different images or xib's for different locales.

Comment: @Cy-4AH but launch images should have given names. (Default .. etc)

Comment: @ArtemZ.Ok. Give them names and write in localized plists.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I have to use InfoPlist.strings to do that job. How should I name my Default@2x.png etc for another localization?

Comment: @ArtemZ. Create localized info.plist and name it whatever you like.

Comment: @Cy-4AH it doesn't work. Just uses unlocalized name

Comment: @ArtemZ. use different names in different plists.

Comment: @Cy-4AH in my plist.info in English: `"UILaunchImageFile" = "Default"`. In Russian: `"UILaunchImageFile" = "RU-Default"`. But doesn't work. Filenames are: RU-Default-568h@2x etc. And for english - Default-568h@2x